# Insert into HBase reading Kafka Message

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka

I am quite new to Kafka + Hbase. Appreciate your help.

We got a Kafka message stream and want to insert data into Hbase reading from Kafka.

I've written a java consumer (Single Topic, Single Partition and One thread) to read the message from the topic. All is fine. With in the thread I am trying to connect Hbase to insert the message into the table which is not working. The moment it's trying to connect to hbase (create the instance of HTable) the kafka thread reading the stream is getting killed. How to overcome this to insert data into Hbase? Greatly appreciate your thoughts and help on this issue.

### Kafka High level Consumer code

```
public void run() {
    ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())

        // Read Message
        System.out.println("Thread " + m_threadNumber + ": " + new String(it.next().message()));       

            //Load into HBase           
            // Instantiating Configuration class
            Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
            config.clear();
            //config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
            //config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");


            config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
            config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
            config.set("hbase.master", "localhost");

            // Instantiating HTable class
            HTable hTable = new HTable(config, "device");

            // Instantiating Put class
            // accepts a row name.
            Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("id14")); 

            // adding values using add() method
            // accepts column family name, qualifier/row name ,value
            p.add(Bytes.toBytes("d_name"), Bytes.toBytes("primary"),Bytes.toBytes("ios"));


            // Saving the put Instance to the HTable.
            hTable.put(p);


            // closing HTable
            hTable.close();
```

### }

Comment: Why are you setting properties in config object in your code? You should have hbase-site.xml property file in your app classpath. I guess that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed this by creating a separate thread for managing hbase connection and managed the class as a singleton.

Comment: @Suri, please post as a answer what you did.